# Href "#" redirect to the current page with form data

Tags: javascript

I want to change the hyperlink of whatever texts that entered. However, when there is no any url entered as the input in the url textarea, the direct will back to the page with removing all the data that entered in the text area. How can I set the page redirect back the page with all the information that has entered when there is no input in the url textarea? Thanks very much!

```
<script>    
    function replacetext(){
        var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x;
    }   
    function replaceurl (){
        var x = document.getElementById("url").value;
        document.getElementById("test").href = x;
        return false;
   }                
</script>
</head>
<body>  
    <p>Text</p>
    <form><textarea id="input" onKeyUp="replacetext();" onKeyPress="replacetext();"></textarea></form><br>
    <p>URL</P>
    <form><textarea id="url"></textarea></form>
    <a id="test" href="#" onclick="replaceurl();">
    <div id="output">erere</div>
    </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You discard the return value of your function.

Try something like this:

```
<a id="test" href="#" onclick="return replaceurl();">
```

### EDIT

Your function returns constant `false`, you should change that to a condition, EG:

```
function replaceurl (){
    var x = document.getElementById("url").value;
    document.getElementById("test").href = x;
    return x.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But now when I enter the url in the url textarea, it won't redirect to that page as well. I still need it to hyperlink to the page when there is an url that entered.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see the issue now. Thanks.